# How do I produce a timestamp/datetime string of a certain format in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a Java program where I want to produce a timestamp/datetime string reflecting the current time of this format: "**2015-02-07T12:07:11.002061**". How exactly would I do that?

Comment: I don't know how this question can be answered without just doing it for u. Have u tried anything urself?

Comment: I looked for regular expressions to feed into a class called simpledateformat, but I didn't see anything matching having six digits after a second with a T in the middle

Comment: what is this 12:07:11.002061??, Hours , minutes, seconds, millis and???

Comment: I'm assuming microseconds I guess?

Comment: The last three digits of the microseconds won't be very useful :-) Just discovered that only SSS works. Use SSS000 - no system will give you the last three accurately.

Answer (score 1):

You question can be solver without joda or 3rd libs..

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date()));
```

this will print...

> 2016-03-09T19:04:53.000707
>
> 2016-03-09T19:04:53.000707
>
> 2016-03-09T19:04:53.000708

Comment: SSSSSS doesn't work with SimpleDateFormat. Use SSS000. (Sorry)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat also is not thread safe and that will not be fixed. So while it works it is really not recommended to use. That's why I recommended new java time package from java 8 or some 3d party libraries for earlier versions of Java

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.8 has the full range of formatting capabilities. This doesn't mean that micro- and nanoseconds are real.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```